# SQL query over three tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have to create a database for my school and now I have these three tables:

```
Note                               Examination               Subject
+------+------+------+--------+    +------+----+--------+    +------+----------+
| _idS | _idP | Note | Punkte |    | _idP | idF| Thema  |    | _idF |   Name   |
+------+------+------+--------+    +------+----+--------+    +------+----------+
|    1 |    2 |    4 |     55 |    |    1 |  2 | Test 1 |    |    1 | Englisch |
|    2 |    2 |    2 |     80 |    |    2 |  4 | Test 2 |    |    2 | Deutsch  |
|    3 |    2 |    1 |     95 |    |    3 |  4 | Test 3 |    |    3 | Mathe    |
|    1 |    3 |    1 |     90 |    +------+----+--------+    |    4 | Physik   |
+------+------+------+--------+                              +------+----------+
```

Now I want to select all `Notes` from a special subject which is given by the `Name` and a special pupil which is given by his `ID (_idS)`. I tried with something like this:

```
SELECT N._idP, N.Note, N.Punkte, E.Thema FROM Note N, Examination E 
WHERE  N._idS='1' AND N._idP=(
       SELECT E._idP FROM Examination E WHERE E.idF=(
              SELECT S._idF FROM Subject S WHERE S.Name='Physik')
       );

// N._idS=1 is the special pupil
// S.Name='Physik' is the special subject
```

But this does not result in the right output. To make it a bit clearer: I want this output:

```
+--------+--------+----------+---------+
| N._idP | N.Note | N.Punkte | E.Thema |
+--------+--------+----------+---------+
|      2 |      4 |       55 | Test 2  |
|      3 |      1 |       90 | Test 3  |
+--------+--------+----------+---------+
```

What is wrong with my SQL statement and what do I have to change to get the above result?
All column names with an underscore `_` at the beginning are `PRIMARY KEYS`. All other are `FOREIGN KEYS`.

Comment: Is it `ID (_diS)` or `ID (_idS)`?

Comment: It's `ID (_idS)`. Improved it thanks.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? It may not matter, but it always helps to know.

Comment: I use SQLite on Android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with your query is first that there is no condition correlating the outer `Note` and `Examination` tables.

Furthermore, the fact that there is no `JOIN` between those two tables is masked by the fact that you are using old-style non-ANSI join syntax--where tables are listed separated by commas, and the join conditions are in the `WHERE` clause. I recommend that instead you solve this problem with simple `JOINs` and no `IN` clause, and furthermore that you use modern ANSI syntax:

```
SELECT
   N._idP,
   N.Note,
   N.Punkte,
   E.Thema
FROM
   Note AS N
   INNER JOIN Examination AS E
      ON N._idP = E._idP
   INNER JOIN Subject AS S
      On E.idF = S._idF
WHERE
   N._idS = 1
   AND S.Name = 'Physik'
;
```

### [See a Live Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9572f/2) (SQL Server 2008 version)

My apologies for not providing a SQLite example--I don't have a web SQLite installed, and the javascript SQLite version is very, very slow to load.

While the `IN (subquery or correlated subquery)` syntax can be a little easier to understand in one aspect, in my experience its use tends to affect the person conceptually, and get in the way of plain old basic `JOIN` thinking. I encourage you to use `JOIN`s and to default to them over using `IN (subquery)` wherever possible. If you can do that, you'll be able to understand the `IN` queries as well. But it doesn't seem to work the other way around.

One huge benefit of using ANSI `JOIN` syntax is that if you don't have an `ON` clause, the query won't run. It furthermore puts conditions with the tables that need them instead of far away in the `WHERE`clause, and additionally, it separates logically the parts that are considered part of the basic `JOIN` (that these tables would *always* use) and the parts that are considered the special `WHERE` filters for this particular query.

Comment: Thanks @DavidStarkey I was actually starting on that--I appreciate it.

Comment: For me it is easier to understand with a LEFT or RIGHT JOIN. Can you please add one of these to your answer (LEFT JOIN  
preferred). Would be great. And is there a difference in performance or something else if I use INNER or LEFT JOIN?

Comment: In your case: use a `INNER JOIN` on the second and a `LEFT JOIN` on the first. `LEFT JOIN` adds all rows of the left table that match no row of the right table. See the last bullet point on the [manual](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#fromclause) BTW: SQLite treats `,` as a join operator: "There is no difference between the "INNER JOIN", "JOIN" and "," join operators".

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Are you saying that you can do `FROM Note N, Examination  E ON N._idP = E._idP`? If not, then there IS a difference between `JOIN` and `,`. I don't prefer `NATURAL JOIN` even when it's possible because your queries can all break by the simple addition of a column to a table (what if you decided to add `UpdatedDate` to every table in your database--whoops, there goes all your code).

Comment: @Cilenco The only reason you would need a `LEFT JOIN` would be if you want all rows from one table, even if there are no matching rows from the `JOIN`ed table. Could you explain what different result you want? It seems to me that `INNER JOIN` is right, based on your data, but I could be wrong. Also, your statement that `LEFT` and `RIGHT` join are easier to understand is very puzzling. They're not all simple substitutes for each other, so you would never pick them based on which is easier to understand, but based on what effect you want. Is it possible a refresher on `JOIN`s would benefit you?

Comment: @ErikE Yes. It it is possible. Tested it, worked. And read the manual. Quote: "There is no difference between the `INNER JOIN`, `JOIN` and `,` join operators"

Comment: @Johannes Okay,  thanks,  I have no test environment. Can you omit the ON subclause for any of those?

Comment: Sure. Works as the documentation states.

Comment: @Johannes My apologies--you did link the manual and I could have read it myself. I have done so now, and have to say that in my mind, allowing `INNER JOIN` to NOT have an `ON` clause (and thus create a cartesian product) is an **enormous and serious error**. It destroys the very meaning of the keywords and thereby defaces the SQL language! It makes as much sense to allow `CROSS JOIN` to have an `ON` clause. It's as if `javascriptArray[i].method()` suddenly started applying to every element of the array! Just stick with ANSI syntax if you value sense in the slightest.

Comment: Sqlite has a lot of quirks. Most of them are there to remain compatible to other SQL dialects, for example `SELECT foo AS "bar" ...` - although `"bar"` would be a literal string, it is used then as alias to remain compatible with Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT n."_idP", n."Nota", n."Punkte", e."Thema"
FROM "Note" n, "Examination" e, "Subject" s
WHERE n."_idS" = 1
AND n."_idP" =e."_idP"
AND e."idF" = s."idF"
AND s."Name" = 'Physik'
```

Comment: Using old-style non-ANSI join syntax is not best practice.